# Why is Spring parsing my date wrong?

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC controller, with a method that takes a `java.util.Date` object as a parameter:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", params = { "foo", "date" }, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Blah getFoo(@RequestParam String foo, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) Date date) {
        // do something interesting here
    }
}
```

If I feed this a date parameter generated by Moment.js, for example `2015-12-17T12:04:10-05:00`, it seems to act as though I gave it a 12 hour time, because the Date I get out the other end returns this from it's `.toString()`: `Thu Dec 17 00:04:00 EST 2015`. For comparison, if I feed it a time string like `2015-12-17T09:04:10-05:00`, I get the expected `Thu Dec 17 09:04:00 EST 2015`, and `2015-12-17T13:04:10-05:00` yields `Thu Dec 17 13:04:00 EST 2015`.

I've tried various tweaks to the above, such as omitting the `@DateTimeFormat` completely, or using `pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, but I always seem to get the same result.

Is this a possible bug in Spring? Or, is there some bit of configuration I may be missing?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.0.

Comment: seems a timezone issue

Comment: @sidgate - if it were a timezone issue, I'd expect to see odd offsets (which I don't)... it's parsing the timezone part just fine. It just seems to think "12:04" is "12:04 AM", even though it interprets "13:04" as "1:04 PM" correctly...

Comment: do you want a am/pm time ? and you're getting 24HH time ? that's the error ?

Comment: @reos - The ISO Date Time format is a "24 hour" format. As you can see above, "09:04" is correctly parsed as "9:04 AM", and "13:04" is correctly parsed as "1:04 PM". The issue is that it *incorrectly* parses "12:04" as "12:04 AM" -- the correct way to write that is "00:04", and "12:04" should be parsed as "12:04 PM"...

Comment: I tried this 2015-12-17T12:04:10.000-0500 and it gave me Thu Dec 17 12:04:10 COT 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a globally registered formatter was involved, and it overrode the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation I had in place. And, that formatter was using the pattern "`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm`, which is why I was seeing the ambiguity with parsing around noon...

Removing that formatter from my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)` method seemed to be enough to allow the @DateTimeFormat to kick in. I also found I had to use the pattern above, rather than the `iso = ISO.DATE_TIME` flavor, because my data didn't have the fractional seconds included.